# Adding a class to link_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a following code which displays a 'delete' link:

```
<%= link_to :class => 'some_class', :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }  do
  <span>Delete</span>
<% end %>
```

But for some reason ROR is not adding `some_class` to `a` tag. Have you any idea what can i do to fix it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the URL as the first parameter, then the html options, e.g.:

```
<%= link_to resource_path(@resource), :class => 'some_class', :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }  do
  <span>Delete</span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually found this to be a working solution with Rails 4.2

```
<%= link_to(resource_path(@resource), class: "project-card clearfix") do %>
    <h1>Your html here</h1>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a controller and action, like edit and destroy, do it as follow:

```
<%= link_to url_for(controller: controller_name, action: :edit, id: item.id), class: "btn btn-link btn-warning btn-just-icon edit" do %>
  <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
<% end %>
<%= link_to url_for(controller: controller_name, action: :destroy, id: item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: t('common.confirm') }, class: 'btn btn-link btn-danger btn-just-icon remove' do %>
  <i class="material-icons">close</i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

The link_to docs:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
```

So you'd want

```
<%= link_to <span>Delete</span>, '/someurl', :class=>'some_class', :method=>:delete, .... %>
```

Comment: This is the version without the block and will also escape the body, so the span tag will appear as a literal string.

Comment: To correctly achieve the same thing with this form you'd need to add a call to `html_safe` on the body string, e.g.: `link_to "<span>Delete</span>".html_safe, url, options`

Comment: why the use of <span> is needed, please let me know it would be of great help

Comment: I can't answer that, the OP can. I'm guessing for CSS styling?

Comment: this question is solved but i'll eplain it: the `<span>` was just an example. I have more html in `<a>` content