# syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end haml_temp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to apply a `class` attribute to a `link_to` block. Following this SO post: [Adding a class to link_to block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545262/adding-a-class-to-link-to-block)

I have written:

```
 =link_to(who_we_are_path), :class => 'top-nav-anchor' do
        WHO WE ARE
        .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
```

However I get the following error:

```
al/app/views/shared/_top_nav.html.haml:110: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end haml_temp = link_to(who_we_are_path), :class => 'top-nav-anchor' do
```

I get the same error using the new syntax:

```
 =link_to(who_we_are_path), class:'top-nav-anchor' do
        WHO WE ARE
        .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
```

Comment: you remove `(` and `)` ... and try

Comment: Or move that `:class` thing inside of the parentheses. And don't blindly copy random code from stackoverflow (without understanding it first). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around the path...

```
 =link_to who_we_are_path, class:'top-nav-anchor' do
    WHO WE ARE
    .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
```